# Suggestions for creating a mobile version of an existing ASP.Net 3.5 application

Tags: asp.net, performance, telerik, mobile-website

I have an existing web application developed in ASP.Net F/W 3.5 and a mobile version of the same needs to be created.

I would like to have some suggestions on:

1. Where should I start? Are there some links & sites that would give me more clarity on how to approach this requirement?
2. Are there any ASP.Net/IIS features or Visual Studio options that might ease this mobile version creation?
3. As there are RadControls & AJAX used throughout the application, what should I be careful about?
4. Will it require every form in the UI to be replaced and take the same time as the old UI creation?
5. What should I be considering from the performance/optimization point of view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. just simplify your design, you can download samples from http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/5d9cd41a-7438-495a-9a46-7470e7ec8576/Nokia_Mobile_Web_Templates.html
2. Although asp.net has mobile web controls but they haven;t been updated quite a while. Besides there is no need for that.
3. If you target modern devices like iPhone or Android or WM7 it should be ok. But you should be carefull about MS ajax controls. They load quite large script sizes.
4. It will require a new design.
5. For a good experience I try to make site(s) as simple as possible and finger/touch friendly.
   Try to keep page/image/script sizes small

Comment: Is it that i should be targeting only a predefined set of devices before heading with the conversion as i could infer from the template provided? Also, are there any generalized categorization of devices across various phones?

Comment: If you talking about nokia's templates although they are for high end symbian devices, they would work for any high end device. Desicion about which devices to target depends on your target market and nature of your site. If you target industrialized countries I'd say go for high end design

Answer (score 2):

From a technical standpoint, needing to do a separate mobile version is pretty moot. At least in the developed world, modern smartphone browsers and mobile networks are good enough that they can handle most things one can throw at them. They are obviously a bit more sensitive to bloated scripts and images, but you should be optimizing that stuff anyhow.

The reason to handle mobile separately is use case -- people using mobile sites are after different things than folks using the full-boned versions. Mobile usage tends to be hurried and pointed at solving a very specific problem -- where is the bathroom? How much is this laptop on amazon? When does the show start? Whereas desktop users tend to be a bit more relaxed. Then layer on top a multi-touch style interface and you are looking at a whole different beast. To the point one almost thinks of doing mobile clients for your services not mobile websites per se.

Comment: As i understand, need to bother about the optimization for migrating to a mobile view.However,do you really think a need for mobile version id to serve clients specific and immediate needs?, as i believe it is much more than that.

Comment: Also, won't it be a one time effort to make a mobile website rather than developing mobile clients for the services as i might need to develop different applications for the different devices?

Comment: It can be -- the fundamental point is that the mobile version solves different problems and has different use cases than the full-blown version. And I think the mobile web is a moving enough target that you will be redoing everything every year or two anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I read about some mobile devices support improvements in the recent version of the telerik ajax controls (see more [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/kamenbundev/posts/10-11-17/introducing_the_touchscrollextender_in_q3_2010.aspx)). On top of that they had some additional enhancements in mind for the Q1 2011 release - I suppose that they will perform pretty decently on a mobile version of your web app, provided that they are not native mobile components though :)

Comment: Thank you for the link.I need to dig deeper for being at a comfortable stand.